# Encrypted Drives

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I have just made a huge mistake. I encrypted my boot drive and now cannot boot. is there a way to unencrypt my drive in the setup or bios?

Comment: No. You made backups, didn't you? You can try to boot from a live USB/DVD/CD and decrypt the drive using your passphrase. Then copy your important files in an USB drive and start over again.

Comment: Depending on *how* you encrypted your hard drive you can use live media to decrypt it. If you haven't made changes in the BIOS manually then it's safe to assume that which ever encryption process you followed also hasn't made any changes.

Comment: I found that if you encrypt them, but don't save the changes, when you reboot from a hard shutdown, they are not encrypted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try the following:
Boot from a live CD/DVD/USB and then select the option to manually install Ubuntu. Now choose the correct options to mount the root partition to / and the home partition to /home. Make sure you DO NOT select the option to format those partitions, Now choose the option to mount the boot partition to /boot and now you DO select the option to format this partition. The installer will now install a fresh unencrypted boot partition while keeping the other two partitions untouched so you don't loose important data. When this finishes you are able to boot normally and you should be able to decrypt the other partitions using your passphrase. This will only work when you have your boot files on a separate partition.